# Why is Google Analytics working on simulator not on the iPAD (iOS 8)?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am using google analytics in iOS 8. If I am working on simulator 6+ (iOS8) it shows updates on Google Analytics web window, even real time also. But when working on iPAD (iOS 8), it shows no updates on Google Analytics web window. Is there some kind of permission issue or so? 
All I see is [GAIBatchingDispatcher hitsForDispatch] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:281): No pending hits."

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, it was driving me crazy.  Eventually I turned Wi-Fi off on the phone, and let it use the cell network, and then GA started working.  It continued working after I turned Wi-Fi back on.  It doesn't make any sense, but I thought I'd put this here in case it helps someone else.